# Submit job to specific task manager in flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have 4 taskmanager (tm) each running with one worker thread.
We tried with multiple worker thread in each task manager but it randomly submits DIFFERENT app to worker thread of one task manager. Now the problem is if any application fails it brings down the entire tm bringing down all other apps.

So can i submit my applucation to specific tm so that all worker threads in that tm runs only one application (multithreaded). Any impact to that application will not be there on other apps.

Answer (score 0):

The Flink scheduler does not provide this level of control. For better isolation, per-job or application clusters are the way to go.

[Application Deployment in Flink: Current State and the new Application Mode](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/07/14/application-mode.html).